# how to add \ before a special char

Tags: android, regex

I am trying to send a string to a server and need to add \ before a special char (for example: replace "test '" with "test \'"). I wrote :

```
public static String handleSpecialChars(String str){
if (str!=null){
    Log.d("Common handleSpecialChars",str);
    str = str.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}]", "\\$1");
   }
   return str;
}
```

but I got "test $1" instead (probably because the \ referring to the $). So I also wrote :

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}]", "\\\\$1");
```

but than I got "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your regex doesn't make much sense, what should it be doing? But for your question, as you have no matching group in your regex, $1 refers to nothing. $0 would refer to the matched string (or \0, don't know in java)

Comment: usually you use brackets `(` & `)` to capture in regex

Comment: Also, consider using handleSpecialChars(String in) and creating a local String out where out = in.replaceAll(...) and return out.

Comment: you are right - Loamhoof I needed to use $0 instead of $1. I am using a lot of Perl and in this language I use $1 for the first item.